# React-Native: Use SQlite Database ifor Android on Windows

Tags: android, node.js, windows, sqlite, react-native

I'm trying a demo app in `React-Native`having `SQLite Database`. But as per the [link](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#how-to-use-android) suggested I Run the command `npm install --save react-native-sqlite-storage` in my project's main repository but I'm getting following error on Windows & but the same command woks flawless on Mac..what is wrong with windows then..please help me..

```
D:\ReactNative Study\RNSQLiteDemo\RNSQLiteDemo>npm install --save react-native-s
qlite-storage
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install D:\ReactNative Study\RNSQLiteDemo\RNSQLiteDemo\node_m
odules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\ReactNative Study\RNSQLiteDemo\RNSQLiteDemo\node_modules\bufferutil>if not de
fined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\no
de-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node
rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK
 for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual
 Studio 2008.  [D:\ReactNative Study\RNSQLiteDemo\RNSQLiteDemo\node_modules\buf
ferutil\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\ReactNative Study\RNSQLiteDemo\RNSQLiteDemo\node_modules\bufferu
til
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:bufferutil bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil Exit status 1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install D:\ReactNative Study\RNSQLiteDemo\RNSQLiteDemo\no
de_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\ReactNative Study\RNSQLiteDemo\RNSQLiteDemo\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if no
t defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bi
n\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (no
de  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK
 for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual
 Studio 2008.  [D:\ReactNative Study\RNSQLiteDemo\RNSQLiteDemo\node_modules\utf
-8-validate\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\ReactNative Study\RNSQLiteDemo\RNSQLiteDemo\node_modules\utf-8-v
alidate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`

npm WARN install:utf-8-validate Exit status 1
RNSQLiteDemo@0.0.1 D:\ReactNative Study\RNSQLiteDemo\RNSQLiteDemo
└── react-native-sqlite-storage@2.1.1
```

Comment: you can install this package https://github.com/almost/react-native-sqlite

Comment: @Kastriot Dreshaj  good one...that package has no android impl...

Answer (score 0):

Could the be an issue with your local node.js version on Windows? There is nothing in that package that should require any additional tweaking therefore I am really tempted to say it is your node.js version on Windows...perhaps it is corrupted? try upgrading...

Seems like it is trying to rebuild your local node-gyp and can't find compiler on Windows to complete the job...but it has nothing to do with the sqlite-storage package...

BTW react-native-sqlite does not have Android version and is still very much in early dev...@Kastriot Dreshaj